# Read element of a dynamic array in c

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, visual-studio-code

I am using VScode as my IDE. So I created an array, and each element of the array stores a pointer to  a linked list . My code is shown as below:

```
typedef struct AdjStopList
{
    char stopName[20]; //name of stop bus is equal or less than 20 characters
    int numOfAdjStp;   //number of adjacent stops to this stop
    struct BusAtStopList *buslist;  // store all the buses passing this stop in a linked list
    struct AdjStopNode *first; //pointed at the first AdjBusStop of the linked list
    struct AdjStopNode *last;  //pointed at the first AdjBusStop of the linked list
} AdjStopList;

typedef struct BusNetwork
{
    int nBusStop; //number of bus stops in the newwork
    struct AdjStopList **stops;
} BusNetwork;

//create a new empty AdjBusStopList
AdjStopList *newAdjStopList()
{
    AdjStopList *newList = (AdjStopList *)malloc(sizeof(AdjStopList));
    newList->buslist = newBusAtStopList();
    assert(newList != NULL);
   // memset(newList, NULL, 20 * sizeof(newList[0]));
    newList->first = NULL;
    newList->last = NULL;
    newList->numOfAdjStp = 0;
    return newList;
}
```

I tried to use a while loop to assign `stopName` with `"test"` in a function

```
BusNetwork *newBusNetwork(int n, const char *BusStops)
{
    BusNetwork *newBN;
    newBN = malloc(sizeof(BusNetwork));
    assert(newBN != NULL);

    newBN->nBusStop = n;
    newBN->stops = malloc(n * sizeof(AdjStopList *));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        newBN->stops[i] = newAdjStopList();
        strcpy(newBN->stops[i]->stopName, "test");
    }
        
    //rest of the function
}
```

Then when I watch the variable `(struct AdjStopList (**)[46])newBN->array` in VScode, it seems only the first element of the array has been processed correctly, e.g. `newBN->array[0]->stopName` is `test`. The rest elements of the array still have random garbage values, e.g. `newBN->array[1]->stopName`.

Can anyone see why this is happening, please?

Q1: Is my use of index `i` wrong?

Q2: I expected when `i = 0`, `newBN->stops[i] = newAdjStopList();` would only allocate memory to the first element.
After I run  `newBN->stops[i] = newAdjStopList();`, as can be seen in the below screenshot, `newBN->stops[1]` has also been allocated memory. However, `numOfAdjStop' doesn't equal to 0. Why...
[image]
Q3: Is it the way how I watch the variables in VScode is wrong? I have learnt this from an online article. I remember it worked for me before. See reference: https://shanepanter.com/2020/12/10/view-point-as-array-vscode.html#references

Comment: I haven't find obvious in your function `newBusNetwork` except that you don't return anything, you may try to manually watch for `newBN->stops[1]->stopName` after line 43 and paste the result here.

Comment: `newBN->stops = malloc(n * sizeof(AdjStopList *));` makes an array of pointers that point to random places in memory. So the watch shows you random data. Then you run `newAdjStopList();` for i=0 which points the 0th one somewhere - but the 1st one can point anywhere because it hasn't been set to NULL or to the result of malloc or anything. So the code is working fine but you are looking at the contents of a pointer to a random place because it is uninitialized until after the loop. If you want the watch to be right use calloc which sets the data to all zeros (or use memset after the malloc).

Comment: `"Q3: ..."` if you are examining allocated blocks allocated using `malloc()` that have not yet been initialized -- then you would expect to see *Indeterminate* values throughout the newly allocated memory until you put something meaningful there.